# I was looking to script (possibly in batch) change the date created on .jpg files to the date authored

Tags: batch-file

I was trying to read the date authored and use that to write to the date created field in batch, I was hoping to do something like this:

```
for /f %f in ('dir /b c:\*.jpg') do Copy FileAttribute "Date Authored"  to "Date Created"
```

I had found a third party tool `nircmd` that has a command that changes the file date like so:

```
nircmd.exe setfiletime "c:\temp\myfile.jpg" "24-06-2003 17:57:11" "22-11-2005 10:21:56"
```

But can't find or know if what I'm trying to do is possible with this tool and a `for` files command.

Answer (score 0):

See [ss64](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) for information on looping through files:

Example: `for /r %i in (*) do echo %i`

As for modifying the creation/modification time of a file, that is not easily doable.  As far as I know, there is no way inherently in CMD or Windows to modify this data, as it poses a security risk.  That being said, you can check out utilities like [Timestomp](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/timestomp/) if you are serious about doing this.